# Ionic3 Change the given date into required format

Tags: android, ios, ionic3

I have used following Html code to display date in template

**Start: {{ startDate | date : 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm:ss A' }}**

The Error iam getting is
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '2018-09-22 18:53:38 PM' for pipe 'DatePipe'

In startdate variable i have given this 2018-09-22 18:53:38 PM as date

Please guide me to fix this error

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems to me that `startDate` is not a `Date` object but just the string `'2018-09-22 18:53:38 PM'`, which is not a [valid input value](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value) for the `DatePipe`.

Comment: Then how to change the string date into valid input.Is there any possibility

Comment: You could remove just the 'PM' of the string, then it would be a valid `date string` which could be converted into a date object using `new Date('2018-09-22 18:53:38')`.

Comment: Thanks, Its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
{{ startDate | date : 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a' }}
```

You tried **D** and **YYYY** capital but Its not valid.
See [the link](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) for more info.